# How to 'Go to Source' for a .Rnw file with knitr on TexStudio

Tags: texstudio, knitr

So, I am TeXStudio and R on Windows 8 and have configured with `knitr` as follows:

```
"C:\Program Files\R\R-3.0.3\bin\Rscript" -e "library(knitr, lib.loc='C:/Users/User/Documents/R/win-library/3.0'); knit2pdf('%.Rnw')"| -synctex=1 -interaction=nonstopmode %.tex.
```

The other options are at their defaults.

But I do not know any means of syncing ('Go to source')from the pdf viewer to the `.Rnw` file. I run into the problem that it calls the `.tex` file instead. Is there any way to fix this from the build options?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

This results from the combination of Synctex and the build chain is rnw -> tex -> pdf. Synctex is originally designed to provide a connection between the tex file and the pdf. It does not know anything about the rnw.

see also: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/210553/24770